# How to download a csv file from mysql table after clicked the file name

Tags: python, mysql, database, csv, phpmyadmin

everyone I need your help to fix my code. I would like to download a csv file form mysql db table. I have import the file name to the table. but when I click the file name I got this http://192.168.1.6/phpmyadmin/2017-08-09065534.csv (The requested URL /phpmyadmin/2017-08-09065534.csv was not found on this server.) But when I delete the /phpmyadmin/ in the browser, like this 192.168.1.6/2017-08-09065534.csv , the file will automatically downloaded. So How do I delete the phpmyadmin ?? Or any idea?
this is my code.

```
enter code here
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import MySQLdb
import glob
UPLOAD_FOLDER ="/var/www/html"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'csv'])


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
  # this has changed from the original example because the original did not work for me
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print '**found file', file.filename
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        conn = MySQLdb.connect (host="192.168.1.6", port=3306, user="root",passwd="12345fitri",db="myDb")
        x = conn.cursor()
            #print 'filename'
        #sql = "INSERT INTO mine (what) values (%s)", (filename,)

        os.chdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        dirfiles=glob.glob("*.csv")
        for file_name in dirfiles:
          #print file_name
          if file_name==filename:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            file_path= os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            #print sql.format (file_path)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mine (what) VALUES (%s)", (filename,))
            conn.commit()
            print "hello"
        except Exception:
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            conn.rollback()
            # for browser, add 'redirect' function on top of 'url_for'
            return url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename)
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000,  threaded=True,debug=True)
```

Comment: Your code show only `upload`, where are your requested `download`?

Comment: actually i dont need requested download in RESTFull API, because i will download the csv file from mysql db table, which is when I click the file name, it will download automatically

Comment: Clarify your Question, the code you show is _**Server Side**_, The File you want to go _** Server => Client**_  You Requested from the Client, so it's _**Download**_?

Comment: The file is sent from client to server, than from the server, send the file to mysql db, so, i will download the file from mysql db in server.

Comment: Your Comment still confus me? The `mysql` is where - **Server** or **Client**? I assume Server, so why _**, i will download the file from mysql db**_? If you **Upload** from Client you want to store the File into the `mysql db`?

Comment: ya, the mysql db is in the server. i upload from the client to web server first, then i store the file to mysql db also, so when i acces the mysql db, i can download the file.

Comment: Sorry **all** your Comments doesn't open my eyes to what you want. Try to rephrasing your Question and make a [mcve].